# Android - Scrollview start at the bottom

Tags: android, scrollview

Is there anyway I can make a Scrollview start on bottom? I tried to:

```
post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
        }
    });
```

And also setting the `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` on the lowest element in the layout.

But I can see it scrolling to the bottom sometimes. The idea is to make it imperceptible to the user.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: listview.smoothScrollBy(x, y); ---> listview.smoothScrollBy(0, 999999);

Answer (score 1):

try with `scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
scrollView.scrollTo(0, scrollView.getBottom());
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I was adding Views dynamically, I also had to allow Android to complete the layout on the content view inside the ScrollView.  I just added a post at the end of the View's queue, that will run after it has completed its layout.  Otherwise, Android was trying to use the old size of the content view, and wasn't scrolling all the way down.

```
mMessagesLayout.addView(messageLayout);
mMessagesLayout.requestLayout();
mMessagesLayout.post(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      mScrollView.scrollTo(0, mScrollView.getBottom());
   }
});
```